# LoadRunner - Two options, different questions for each of them?

Tags: testing, automation, loadrunner

I'm new to LoadRununer but have done the tutorials based on it. Basically I have a test situation where I am testing a website using JavaScript - where a question asking whether single or married etc (can't say exact question, but along same lines).

My question is to find out how to change to different options and have the script answer both when it replays. I was thinking if an if statement would work, but it is not possible to have an if statement in a function.

Thanks all.

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: The language is based in C..

Comment: What do you mean "answer both". A user can answer only one of the options and you should stick to this flow. Do you mean when you run the script twice each time the answer is different?

Answer (score 0):

You need more robust training and a mentor for a period.   Unless you have exceptionally strong foundation skills in all of the core disciplines then the odds of your success are low.      Your question regarding an "if statement" exposes s significant weakness in your foundation skills an your knowledge of the tool.   As a tester you do not want to have question marks over your tool, your test design, your analysis and your application under test.  You want robust "known good" items on your test tool, test design and test analysis as you change the one variant item, the application under test.

Hire an experienced consultant in this space.  Shadow them.  Take copious notes.   Ask lots of questions.    The money you spend on the (even the most expensive) consultant we be a lot less than the money wasted in "learning mode" while at the same time trying to conduct tests.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question properly (I'm not certain I do), I think you want to make the two possible values parameters in VUGen. Then adjust the settings for that parameter appropriately. Probably random.